# Changing the While loop to for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, apache-poi

Hello people here in this extractTable method used while(true). According to method if the condition fail it will be an infinite loop which is a bad programming practice can you people help me out changing while to for or for each

```
private List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> extractTable(XSSFSheet sheet, Cell tablePosition) {
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> table = new ArrayList<>();

    int headerRow = tablePosition.getRowIndex();
    int valuesHeaderColumn = tablePosition.getColumnIndex();

    // read all columns and rows until finding an empty one
    int row = headerRow + 1;
    int col = valuesHeaderColumn + 1;

    // read all columns starting at col
    while (true) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> tableColumn = new HashMap<>();
        Cell headerCell = sheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(col);
        if (headerCell == null)
            break;
        String columnName = headerCell.getStringCellValue().toUpperCase();
        if ("".equals(columnName))
            break;

        // read all rows starting at row
        Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
        while (true) {
            Row valueHeaderRow = sheet.getRow(row);
            if (valueHeaderRow == null)
                break;
            Cell valueHeaderCell = valueHeaderRow.getCell(valuesHeaderColumn);
            String valueHeader = valueHeaderCell.getStringCellValue();
            if ("".equals(valueHeader))
                break;
            Cell valueCell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
            Integer value = (int) valueCell.getNumericCellValue();
            values.put(valueHeader, value);
            row++;
        }

        tableColumn.put(columnName, values);
        // Add the columns map to the list
        table.add(tableColumn);
        col++;
        row = headerRow + 1;
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: "According to method if the condition fail it will be an infinite loop". This is not clear. What method? What condition will fail?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe while(true) ... break is a bad programming practice, look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142144/95609). But to iterate rows and columns of a spreadsheet with POI, it is [recommended](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) that you do it this way:

```
for (Row row: sheet) {
  for (Cell cell: row) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me regarding the above program @jmarkmurphy

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your time.I came up with a solution